# switching between two colors is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, setinterval

What is it that I am missing here so my page switches between these two colors? Thank you !

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var isBlue = false;

setInterval(function(){
    if(isBlue){
        body.style.background = "green";
    } else {
        body.style.background = "white"
    }
},1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never changing the value of `isBlue`, so it's always `false`, so you always set `white` as the background color.

Afrer the `if`/`else`, invert the flag:

```
isBlue = !isBlue;
```

E.g.:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(isBlue){
        body.style.background = "green";
    } else {
        body.style.background = "white"
    }
    isBlue = !isBlue;
},1000);
```

---

Side note: "isBlue" seems an odd name for a flag that sets a *green* background... ;-) (Though to be fair, as I understand it in some cultures there isn't a distinction between blue and green.)

Comment: But if it's not blue, it sets a white background, so I guess half of the logic is correct nonetheless :D

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was playing with it and at one point changed the color from the original blue and forgot about it :). Thanks for the explanation !